# Pointwise Upper Bound

Tags: analysis

Consider $G\in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $G(0)=0$. Then there exists a constant $C$ such that $|G(s)|\leq C|s|$ for all $s\in [-M,M]$, where $M<\infty$.

This statement is part of a proof in Brezis. It's clear by the extreme value theorem that we can definitely pick a uniform upper bound for $G$ on a closed interval. However, how would you go about picking the $C$ above pointwise?

Comment: By picking an uniform upper bound for $G'$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be an upper bound for $G'$ on $[-M,M]$, which is possible because $G'$ is continuous by hypothesis. By the mean value theorem, we have for every $s\in [-M,M]$ $$|G(s) - G(0)|=|G(s)| \leq C|s-0| = C|s| $$

Comment: Mean Value Theorem! Thank you.

Comment: You require $C$ to be an upper bound not just on $G'$, but rather on $|G'|$.